# Probability with Repetition

Tags: probability

Of foods ordered in a food truck, 80% are burgers and 20% are fries.

a. What is the probability that fries will be the next $ 3 $ orders?

b. What is the probability that burgers will be $2$ of the next $3$ orders?

> For a, I considered:$ (\frac{3!}{3!}) x (0.20) x (0.20) x (0.20) = 0.008$
>
> For b, I considered:$ (\frac{3!}{2!}) x (0.80) x (0.80) x (0.20) = 0.384 $

I am not that sure with multiplying the terms with permutation.

Answer (score 1):

a.) Assume that the events $A_1, A_2$ and $A_3$ are independent. Then $$P\left(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3 \right) = P\left(A_1 \right)P\left(A_2 \right)P\left(A_3 \right).$$

b.) Have a look at the binomial distribution.

Comment: You can read $\cap$ as "and".

Comment: The first part can also be solved using binomial distribution.

Comment: Well, to be precise, the answer for the a-part is more general since it only requires independence. But in this case, true, you can consider both via the Binomial distribution.

Comment: If part a could be solved using binomial distribution, how about b? can the principle be applied, too, as in a?

Comment: A direct quote from Wikipedia: "In probability theory and statistics, the binomial distribution with parameters n and p is the discrete probability distribution of the number of successes in a sequence of n independent yes/no experiments, each of which yields success with probability p." In this case you could ask "did I get fries" and you would have p = 0.2

Does this clarify what I mean?